# NGRX effect stale R3Injector after destroying and reinitialising module

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, webpack-module-federation, ngondestroy

I am attempting to use module federation along with ngrx store & ngrx effects in my webapp which is all in working order for the most part. However, I wish to destroy my `NgModuleRef` when switching to another lazy loaded route. Hence if I have one module called **MyAccountModule** at */myaccount* and another module called **Dashboard** at /dashboard then I wish to destroy the **MyAccountModule** when switching to the */dashboard* route and destroy the */dashboard* route when switching back to */myaccount*.

I have achieved this using this code:

```
export class MyAccountModule implements OnDestroy {
  private destroyed$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private currentNgModuleRef: NgModuleRef<MyAccountModule>,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private webSocket: WebsocketService
  ) {

    this.store.dispatch(new InitializeMyAccountModuleAction());
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
        map(event=> event as RouterEvent)
      )
      .subscribe(($evt)=>{
        if (!$evt.url.includes('myaccount')){
           this.currentNgModuleRef.destroy();
        }
      });
    
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {

    this.store.removeReducer('manageAccountState');
    
    if (this.webSocket.sockets.has(environment.wsURL)) this.store.dispatch(new WebsocketDisconnectAction({ wsURL: environment.wsURL }));

    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
```

This works fine and both routes seem to display & function correctly. However, if you were to route from */myaccount* to /dashboard & then back to */myaccount* for example. It seems upon the reinitialising of **MyAccountModule** (*/myaccount*), it does not appear to reinstantiate `EffectsModule.forFeature()`. Meaning that when I trigger an ngrx effect it uses the original `R3Injector` therefore when calling a service within the effect such as a http service it lacks the relevant providers because the instance of the injector is that of the initially loaded module which is now in a destroyed state. Meaning for some reason or another ngrx does not seem to update the state surrounding the running of the contents of `createEffect(()=>` to utilise the newest instance of `R3Injector`.

Therefore I guess my question becomes is there a way to manually destroy `EffectsModule.forFeature()` from memory? If not, is it possible to de-register the effect? Or some way of re-initialising the injector instance provider for the module within the constructor.

The error received is due to it being thrown in `core.js`:

```
assertNotDestroyed() {
        if (this._destroyed) {
            throw new Error('Injector has already been destroyed.');
        }
}
```

where `this = R3Injector` and the value of R3Injector properties includes `_destroyed:true` due to it being the previous instance.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.